# python pygame collisions side of Rectangle

Tags: python, pygame, collision

At this moment I use 4 different rectangles for the collision
like it can be seen in the photo

[image]

this is a part of my code that I use

```
    mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft = pygame.Rect((x,y+27),(1,5))
    mainCharacterCoordinatesRight = pygame.Rect((x+28,y+27),(1,5))
    mainCharacterCoordinatesTop = pygame.Rect((x+2,y+20),(26,5))
    mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom = pygame.Rect((x+2,y+27),(26,7))


    if (keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT] and not any(mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft.colliderect(treeCoordinates) for treeCoordinates in treeCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft.colliderect(crossCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft.colliderect(leftborder) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft.colliderect(wellCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft.colliderect(trainCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesLeft.colliderect(graveyardCoordinates)):
        mainCharacterImage=pygame.image.load(mainCharacterLeft[counter])
        counter = (counter + 1) % len(mainCharacterLeft)
        x -= 2
        CameraX -= 2

    if (keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not any(mainCharacterCoordinatesRight.colliderect(treeCoordinates) for treeCoordinates in treeCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesRight.colliderect(crossCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesRight.colliderect(rightborder) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesRight.colliderect(wellCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesRight.colliderect(trainCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesRight.colliderect(graveyardCoordinates)):
        mainCharacterImage=pygame.image.load(mainCharacterRight[counter])
        counter = (counter + 1) % len(mainCharacterRight)
        x += 2
        CameraX += 2

    if (keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP] and not any(mainCharacterCoordinatesTop.colliderect(treeCoordinates) for treeCoordinates in treeCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesTop.colliderect(crossCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesTop.colliderect(topborder) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesTop.colliderect(wellCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesTop.colliderect(trainCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesTop.colliderect(graveyardCoordinates)):
        mainCharacterImage=pygame.image.load(mainCharacterBack[counter])
        counter = (counter + 1) % len(mainCharacterBack)
        y -= 2
        CameraY -= 2

    if (keys_pressed[pygame.K_DOWN] and not any(mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom.colliderect(treeCoordinates) for treeCoordinates in treeCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom.colliderect(crossCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom.colliderect(bottomborder) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom.colliderect(wellCoordinates)and not mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom.colliderect(trainCoordinates) and not mainCharacterCoordinatesBottom.colliderect(graveyardCoordinates)):
        mainCharacterImage=pygame.image.load(mainCharacterFront[counter])
        counter = (counter + 1) % len(mainCharacterFront)
        y += 2
        CameraY += 2
```

Is it possible to have just one rectangle for the maincharacter and tell the program just to check each of the side of the rectangle??

Comment: If you're going for a tile based approach like pokemon, you could just have a grid and check that there is no item in the grid, otherwise, why not just use the rectangle of your characters image? :P

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a rectangle for the main character (which involves a lot of explicit boundary checking), use a [sprite](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) instead. The sprite class includes collision detection, as well as tons of other useful functions.

It may not seem initially worth the effort of refactoring, but as your game grows you will be happy you did it.